# Subspaces equality condition

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following subspaces of $R^4$:

$V = L((1, 1, 2, 2),(2, 0, 2, 1))$

$U = {(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) : x_1 + x_2 − x_3 = 2x_1 − 3x_3 + 2x_4 = 0}$

How can I prove that $V = U$? My first attempt would be the following:

- Find a basis of $V$ and a basis of $U$
- If $\dim(V) = \dim(U)$ then $V=U$, otherwise they are not representing the same subspace.

Is my guess correct? If not, can you show me how to practically solve this exercise?

Comment: It is not true that if subspaces have the same dimension, then they are the same. For instance the $x$ and $y$-axes in $\mathbb{R}^2$ both have dimension 1, but are different. However, if you show that one is contained in the other, and they both have the same (finite) dimension. then you are ok.

Comment: How can I prove (practically) that one is contained in the other?

Comment: Show that both $(1,1,2,2)$ and $(2,0,2,1)$ belong to $U$.

Comment: To expand on siminore, you have collections $U$ and $V$ defined as those vectors satisfying certain properties (in the first case, being in the span on two given vectors, in the second, satisfying a certain linear equation). So take an arbitrary element of one of the subspaces (so all you know is that it satisfies the defining condition) and show it satisfies the other. In this case, for instance you can take a linear combination of of $(1,1,2,2,),(2,0,2,1)$ and show that satisfies the equation for defining $V$. As a short cut, if you already know $U$ is itself a vector space ...

Comment: ... then it suffices to show that a basis of $V$ is contained in $U$.

Comment: Thank you both of you guys, this is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prove that $\dim U = \dim V$ and that either $U \subset V$ or $V \subset U$. Different subspaces can have the same dimension...

By direct inspection, prove that $(1,1,2,2)$ and $(2,0,2,1)$ belong to $U$. Then prove that $\dim U=2$.